# Why did my question still get marked as duplicate even after my clarification?

Tags: discussion

I asked [*How to recover a pickled class and it's instances*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34261379/3904031) and after I accepted an answer, it was marked as a possible duplicate. I added a substantial comment to the question explaining why this question is different than the one flagged by the duplicate message.

Note: the pickling of the class does result in the creation of a file.

1. My question is about pickling the actual class itself. The other question was about recovering the values of the class variables - not the class itself. I can create a file pickling the class, but can not recover the class from that file.
2. I had, one day earlier, specified in the EDIT that I needed a solution using `pickle` because I don't have `dill`. The other answer cited specifies the use of `dill`.

Further my comments in the accepted answer mentions that the documentation actually says at one point that top level classes CAN be pickled. As this doesn't seem to be 100% true, I think it's an important distinction.

Then more people voted to mark as duplicate disregarding my explanation why it was not duplicate. To me these seem to be clearly different questions. Is there a way to appeal?

Comment: Looking at the people who are linked in that duplicate marking, only one of them has actual activity in the python tag. Sigh.

Comment: @Gimby That's irrelevant. How much Python tag experience do you think people need to understand "I don't want to use dill"?

Comment: @BilltheLizard So if I understand you correctly: it was pretty much dupe hammered when even someone without domain knowledge could have seen it was not so. Double sigh if true, color me stupid if not true. Regardless, the question is reopened.

Comment: @Gimby It's entirely possible that people think not wanting to install a readily available open-source library isn't a good enough reason for asking a separate question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I've just left a few reasons as a new comment to the question. How is withholding an answer is good in this case? Also, at least one sentence in the documentation says a top level class can be pickled, and it does produce a file. The answer is that it shouldn't, and now I (and presumably other readers) know why.  Thanks all for help with my question!